# Measure how much time the ClassLoader takes to load class or jar

Tags: java, performance, time, classloader

How to know how much time a specific .class or .jar takes to be loaded by the ClassLoader?

The JVM option `-verbose:class` allows to know in which order the ClassLoader loads .class and jar. But it doesn't tell me if a specific .jar take a lot of time or not to be loaded.

Comment: It only load individual classes and individual methods on demand.  A lot of the delay is in running the static initialiser blocks and work done between loading of classes and methods.  I am not sure how useful individual accounting would be.  Have you tried a CPU profiler?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the Classloader and add measurements to the compile() method.

Answer (score 1):

BTrace would help

here is a sample script just trace class load
you can add time yourself
http://kenai.com/projects/btrace/sources/hg/content/samples/Classload.java?rev=267